# Shibboleth Configuration

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am very (very) new to shibboleth, currently I am doing configuration by editing the shobboleth2.xml and I use shibboleth 2.4 but I am getting following error when I restart the shibboleth.

```
shibd error: unable to run config check as user 
Restarting Shibboleth 2 daemon: 2013-03-04 13:15:27 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 28, column 40, message: attribute 'homeUrl' is not declared for element 'ApplicationDefaults'
2013-03-04 13:15:27 ERROR Shibboleth.Config : error while loading resource (/etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
2013-03-04 13:15:27 FATAL Shibboleth.Config : caught exception while loading configuration: XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
configuration is invalid, check console for specific problems
```

In my shibboleth2.xml I have already added the homeUrl.

```
<!-- The ApplicationDefaults element is where most of Shibboleth's SAML bits are defined. -->
<ApplicationDefaults id="default"
         policyId="default"
         entityID="https://somesite.com/shibboleth/default"
         homeUrl="https://somesite.com/"
                     REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
         signing="false" encryption="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute "homeUrl" from your <ApplicationDefaults /> element.

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default"
     policyId="default"
     entityID="https://somesite.com/shibboleth/default"
                 REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
     signing="false" encryption="false">
```